# Как сделать 2 тултипа при наведении на одну кнопку?

Tags: c#, winforms

Я хочу сделать всплывающее окно при наведении на кнопку одну и ту же.Одна и та же кнопка выполняет действие восстановления(увеличение) формы и развертывании(уменьшении)формы и хотел бы реализовать 2 всплывающих окна при разных действиях той же кнопки, но не вышло.
Вот мой код:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Get_Table("ID_route as 'id маршрута', Route_number as 'номер маршрута',destination as 'пункт назначения',Cost_destination as 'стоимость за проезд',district as 'район'," +
            "Sending_time as 'Время отправки' From auto.route", 1);
        Get_Table("id_Ticket as 'id билета', Place as 'Место', Name as 'ФИО пассажира', passport as 'пасспорт' From auto.ticket", 2);
        Get_Table("id_driver as 'id водителя', Nname as 'ФИО водителя', Birthday as 'Дата рождения', Passport as 'Пасспорт' From auto.driver", 3);
        Get_Table("id_Bus as 'id автобуса', number as 'Номер', Model as 'Модель', License_plate_number as 'Номерной знак'," +
            "number_of_seats as 'Количество мест' From auto.bus", 4);
        Get_Table("id_Dispatcher as 'id диспетчера', Name as 'ФИО диспетчера',Birthday as 'Дата рождения',Address as 'Адрес' From auto.dispatcher", 5);
        textBox1.Text = "0";
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;
        ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
        t.SetToolTip(button3, "Выберите строки из таблиц для создания записи билета!!!");
        ToolTip t5 = new ToolTip();
        t5.SetToolTip(button6, "Закрыть форму");
        ToolTip t6 = new ToolTip();
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
        {
            t6.SetToolTip(button5, "Развернуть форму");
        }
        else if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
        {
            t6.SetToolTip(button5, "Вернуть форму");
        }
        ToolTip t7 = new ToolTip();
        t7.SetToolTip(button7, "Свернуть форму");
    }
```

вот и код в котором я делаю восстановление и развертывании формы:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }
        else
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Тут представлен не весь код, рискну предположить что ToolTip надо обновлять каждый раз когда меняешь форму, а не один раз при создании.

Comment: `но не вышло` - отличное описание проблемы, но можно немного деталей? Что за обрывок кода с тултипом, где он лежит, когда выполняется?

Comment: @aepot код с тултипом лежит в методе формы Load() код то работает но можно как то сделать 2 всплывающих окна в зависимости что сделаю разверну или восстановлю форму

Comment: @aepot я редактировал свой вопрос вставил полный код куда вставляю тултип

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновлять текст на тултипе надо после каждого изменения состояния формы, а не один раз.

```
private ToolTip windowStateTooltip = new ToolTip();

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ... ваш остальной код

    new ToolTip().SetToolTip(button3, "Выберите строки из таблиц для создания записи билета!!!");
    new ToolTip().SetToolTip(button6, "Закрыть");
    new ToolTip().SetToolTip(button7, "Свернуть");
    UpdateWindowStateTooltip();
}

private void UpdateWindowStateTooltip()
{
    windowStateTooltip.SetToolTip(button5, WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal ? "Развернуть" : "Восстановить");
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WindowState = WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal ? FormWindowState.Maximized : FormWindowState.Normal;
    UpdateWindowStateTooltip();
}
```

Еще не называйте окно "формой", ну потому что оно окно. "Форма" - это термин Winforms.

Еще обратите внимание на то что состоянием окна можно управлять не только через ваши кнопки. Например можно через контекстное меню панели задач (Shift+Правый клик по иконке открытого приложения).

Поэтому лучше сделать так.

```
private ToolTip windowStateTooltip = new ToolTip();
private FormWindowState LastWindowState;

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ... ваш остальной код

    new ToolTip().SetToolTip(button3, "Выберите строки из таблиц для создания записи билета!!!");
    new ToolTip().SetToolTip(button6, "Закрыть");
    new ToolTip().SetToolTip(button7, "Свернуть");
    UpdateWindowStateTooltip();
}

private void UpdateWindowStateTooltip()
{
    windowStateTooltip.SetToolTip(button5, WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal ? "Развернуть" : "Восстановить");
}

protected override void OnClientSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState != LastWindowState)
    {
        LastWindowState = WindowState;
        UpdateWindowStateTooltip();
    }
    base.OnClientSizeChanged(e);
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WindowState = WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal ? FormWindowState.Maximized : FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

Comment: спасибо я уяснил ваше замечание